# При выполнении docker-compose не стартует один контейнер

Tags: docker, docker-compose

При выполнении **docker-compose up -d** не стартует контейнер **web**. Но если еще раз выполнить **docker-compose up -d** он выполняться. То есть он не запускаться не с первого раза, в чем может быть проблема? (скрины консоли и файл docker-compose.yml ниже)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
version: '3'
services:
 web:
  image: nginx
  ports:
   - "8000:80"
  volumes:
   - ./:/var/www/html
   - ./site.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

 php:
  build: .
  volumes:
   - ./:/var/www/html
  links:
   - postgres
   - redis

 redis:
  image: redis
  ports: 
   - "6379:6379"

 postgres:
  image: postgres
  ports:
   - "5432:5432"
```

Comment: Смотрите в логи, там о проблеме должно быть написано.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш контейнер скорее всего не "не запускается", а "запускается и тут же падает".

Предположу, что ваше приложение на запуске проверяет доступность какого-либо из связанных сервисов, и, не находя его (он еще не успел запуститься), падает. Ко второму запуску сервис уже поднят, поэтому все проходит успешно.

Answer (score 1):

В 3 версии формата не рекомендуется использовать `links`.

Попробуйте использовать `depends_on` (мануал по [depends_on](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#depends_on)).

Вот в этой [ссылке](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/) рассказывается как правильно использовать порядок запуска в Compose.